# Very little attention for a bountied question

Tags: discussion, questions

I have a question which I asked 10 days ago which could affect over 10 000 people playing Shadow Fight 2 on Windows computers. But it only reached about 30 views after 3 days.

So I offered a 50-rep bounty. Yet, my question hasn't even reached 100 views.

Why isn't my question receiving many views, and what can I do to improve it?

**My question:** [Strangely low framerate in Shadow Fight 2 for Windows 8](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/214131/strangely-low-framerate-in-shadow-fight-2-for-windows-8)

Comment: Sometimes, there just aren't very many people who play that game, and no amount of bounty will help change that.

Comment: Well, I can tell you that I was one of the people who contributed to those first 30 views :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bounty doesn't guarantee views. It is just a way of hopefully getting attention. If it isn't a game a lot of people on the site play, etc, it might not get attention.

The best you can hope for is to make sure it is a clearly written, well detailed question and perhaps consider another bounty.